# Color bleeding and polymode

Tags: debugging, auctex, font-lock, polymode

I sometimes experience "color bleeding" in auctex, and wasn't able to find the source of the problem for a long time. In particular because I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I also can't post documents where it occurred because they contain non public data, are complex, not minimal etc.

Now I noticed that the problem is gone if I comment out the following sections of my init.el:

```
(defcustom pm-inner/python   (pm-inner-chunkmode "python"
         :head-matcher "\\\\begin{\\(pycode\\|pythontexcustomcode\\|sagecode\\)}\\(\\[[^]\\]+]\\)?"
         :tail-matcher "\\\\end{\\(pycode\\|pythontexcustomcode\\|sagecode\\)}"
         :mode 'python-mode)   "python typical chunk."   :group 'innermodes   :type 'object)

(defcustom pm-poly/latex-python
  (pm-polymode "latex-python"
           :hostmode 'pm-host/latex
           :innermodes '(pm-inner/python))
  "latex-python typical polymode."
  :group 'polymodes
  :type 'object)

(define-polymode poly-latex+python-mode pm-poly/latex-python)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tex$" . poly-latex+python-mode))
```

It is a [polymode](https://polymode.github.io/) configuration for automatically going to python mode inside a latex document if python-chunks (inside a pycode environment for example) occur.

So do you have any idea, why this code could lead to [color bleeding](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Known-problems.html) and how to investigate it further (in particular to get a reproducible minimal example which shows the problem).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "colour bleeding", perhaps with a screenshot if that helps to make it clearer?

Comment: What @FranBurstall said - define color bleeding.

Comment: I added a link to the auctex manual for a description of the problem. I cannot post a screenshot because I can't reproduce the problem with documents I could share in public.

Comment: @student - Does it mean that you have unbalanced number of `$` in your `pycode` environment and that causes the bleeding?

Comment: @student - And I think your regexp for matching the opt. argument `\\(\\[[^]\\]+]\\)?` is wrong; it should read `"\\(\\[[^]]+\\]\\)?"`